# Missing page redirector Laravel implements Redirector

Tags: php, laravel

I am using spatie missing page redirector https://github.com/spatie/laravel-missing-page-redirector . this libray have interface to implement the interface name Redirector. I wanted to implements the interface to merge both my class(which implements Redirtor) array  config/missing-page-redirector.php array but this not working here is my config/missing-page-redirector.php

```
return [

'redirector' => \Spatie\MissingPageRedirector\Redirector\ConfigurationRedirector::class,



'redirect_status_codes' => [],

'redirects' => [],

];
```

below is my class which implements spatie interface Redirector

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Model\Redirect;
use Spatie\MissingPageRedirector\Redirector\Redirector;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class MyRedirector implements Redirector
{
  public function getRedirectsFor(Request $request): array
  {
    // Get the redirects from the config
    $configRedirects = config('missing-page-redirector.redirects');

    // Merge both values
    return array_merge(['/old/url' => '/new/url'], $configRedirects);
  }
}
```

Can you please let me know what is problem?

Comment: Please correct the spelling errors and add missing interpunction. Hard to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your wrote your own redirector. Your config still says

```php
'redirector' => \Spatie\MissingPageRedirector\Redirector\ConfigurationRedirector::class,
```

which uses the redirector from Spatie. But it should use your custom `MyRedirector` class.

```php
'redirector' => \App\Services\MyRedirector::class,
```

Comment: oh yes, this working well now, thank you for the solution